# How to correctly calculate Big-O Time Complexity for for-loops? (C#)

Tags: c#, for-loop, time-complexity, big-o

I'm studying how to properly calculate Big O notation and was wondering if anyone could confirm whether my work is correct of not (my comments on each line):

```cs
    int n = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());                 // 1

    LinkedList<int> sumSequence = new LinkedList<int>();     // 1

    sumSequence.AddLast(0);                                  // 1
    sumSequence.AddLast(1);                                  // 1

    for (int i = 2; i < n; i++)                              // n + 1
    {
    int currentSum = 0;                                      // n
    for (int j = i - 1; j > 0; j--)                          // n^2 + 1
    {
        currentSum += sumSequence.ElementAt(j);              // n^2
    }                                                           
    sumSequence.AddLast(currentSum);                         // n
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < sumSequence.Count(); i++)            // n + 1
    {
    Console.WriteLine(sumSequence.ElementAt(i));             // n
    }
    //-------------
    // Total:
    // 2n^2 + 5n + 7
    // 2n^2 +5n     <-- Clear constant terms
    // n^2 + n      <-- Clear coeffients
    // n^2          <-- Pick most signification term.
```

I'm fairly that the overall time complexity is Big O(n^2), although I'm unsure if I'm calculating the inner and out for-loops correctly.

[CodePal.ai](https://codepal.ai/big-o-analyzer/csharp) says the following:

**Outer Loop:**

The outer loop for `(int i = 2; i < n; i++)` runs `n - 2` times, so its time complexity is `O(n)`.

**Inner Loop:**

The inner loop for `(int j = i - 1; j > 0; j--)` runs `i - 1` times for each iteration of the outer loop. The total number of iterations for the inner loop is the sum of the first `n - 2` natural numbers, which is equal to `(n-2)(n-1)/2`. Therefore, the time complexity of the inner loop is `O(n^2)`.

So... should I change those lines to equal `n - 2`, and if so - can you explain why? I thought all for-loops equal `n + 1`

Thank you so much everyone, I really do appreciate!

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < sumSequence.Count(); i++)` <-- This is _considerably_ more expensive than you think: consider how Linq's `.Count()` method works.

Comment: _" I thought all for-loops equal n + 1"_ - only when the loop's constituent operations (e.g. the indexer/cursor/iterator increment, get-length, and get-element) are `O(1)` - but you're using various non-`O(1)` methods in your `for` loops, which changes the runtime complexity considerably.

Answer (score 0):

> So... should I change those lines to equal n - 2, and if so - can you explain why? I thought all for-loops equal n + 1

Your question is why a `for` loop from `2` to `n - 1` runs `n - 2` times? That's basic math, `n - 1 - 2 + 1 = n - 2`.

> should I change

Your side squiggles don't matter, only the most significant polynomial factor matters. `O(n)` is `O(n)`, no matter where you start your loop at.

That said, most of your analysis is wrong. You're using the worst possible collection (a linked list) and both `ElementAt()` and `Count()` are linear, not constant. That makes the first nested loop `O(n^3)` and the second one `O(n^2)`. You have a lot more to learn than just time complexity.

Comment: To be clear, while your choice of data structure is absolutely horrendous, your algorithm could have still been `O(n^2)` if you wrote it properly.